# Heap Dump created by JVM is incomplete

Tags: java, jvm

I want to analyze the memory usage of the application using eclipse MAT, therefore I'm using `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` to create a heapdump. Now if I open it in MAT, it tells me that the heap dump has a size of 127mb which is clearly not everything as the jvm is run with `-Xmx1024m`.

Comment: What is the exact `OutOfMemoryError` you received.? Could you post the stacktrace.?

Comment: Yes, what exactly? Note that you can get an `OutOfMemoryError` for resources other than heap memory! (permgen is a classic example in Oracle/Sun/OpenJDK JVMs).

Answer (score 0):

There are usually two segments of memory in the Java VM (the nursery and the heap), each of which can cause OutOfMemory. You therefore cannot conclude, that the size of the dump file should equal or exceed the -Xmx setting.

Read more on the topic - e.g. here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/garbage_collect.html

Comment: That document is about the JRockit VM (and seemingly not very new, as it's from 2008). The details of garbage collection are *very* implementation dependent, so this does not generally apply to other JVMs.

Comment: Agreed. But I went through this experience with OutOfMemory recently and surprisingly discovered the concept of the nursery. Increasing its space helped me then. I am using IBM JVM / Websphere, and use the -Xmn option to set the nursery space. The article may be old, but I believe it applies to many current situations. But you're right - this is very JVM specific.